# Consume activemq to a log but keep the message in the queue

Tags: java, logging, activemq-classic, consumer

I have an activeMQ app. I want to read the body of incoming messages, but keep the message into the queue. How do I do that? Is there any trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use message browsing feature of ActiveMQ by using `ActiveMQQueueBrowser`

http://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQQueueBrowser.html